# Bash scripting assign ALL output from command to variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get both successful and unsuccessful responses from a ping in a bash script but am unable to thus far.

My code looks like this...

```
ping_results=$(ping -c 4 -q google.com)
```

This works when the ping is successful, but if I don't have an internet connection and I get the result

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

It is printed to the console, and my script appears to exit.

I want both the ping result or error to be stored in the ping_results variable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is because errors go to `stderr` use something like `2&>1` t osend output to stdout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, the simple answer to your question is to redirect stderr to stdout. as what Fredik Phil mentioned in the comments.

instead of:

```
ping_results=$(ping -c 4 -q google.com);
```

use:

```
 ping_results=$(ping -c 4 -q google.com 2>&1);
```

or something similar...

However, depending on what you're doing, it might be better to test if the exit code of the ping command is 1 (indicating that the ping is ending in an error), or 0 (indicating that the ping is successful).
the exit code is stored in the variable "$?".