# How to consistently record command output in a variable in UNIX

Tags: shell, variables, scripting, command, ksh

In some cases what I see in a console output is different from what I get recorded after redirection. I see this on Linux/bash but this example is ksh/OpenBSD. Is there a way around this?

For example:

```
# pfctl -ttable -Ttest 123.123.123.123 > result.txt
0/1 addresses match.
# more result.txt
result.txt (END)
```

In other words the "0/1 addresses match." is printed on the console, but I cannot for the life of me get it into a file, variable or anything. I've used $() and > which work for most commands, but every now and then there is a command that spits out stuff on the screen but I get nothing via the redirect/pipe. I hope someone can shed light on this peculiarity.

So again contrast this:

```
# OUTP=$(pfctl -tscanners -Ttest 123.123.123.123)
0/1 addresses match.
# echo $OUTP

#
```

(nothing echoing, the variable does not hold the console output) with this:

```
# OUTP=$(date)
# echo $OUTP
Sun Aug 21 08:33:37 PDT 2016
#
```

(the variable contains the entire console output)

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash scripting assign ALL output from command to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455680/bash-scripting-assign-all-output-from-command-to-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command has 2 different output streams.
You need to rederict the second (stderr) to the first.

```
pfctl -ttable -Ttest 123.123.123.123 > result.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Omg I had tried 2>&1 but had put that right after the command. Putting it at the very end works! For both cases. Thanks!

Comment: I get confused every time I use it. I try to remember it with : connect `2` with the target of `1`.  When you first connect stderr to the console, redirecting stdout is out of the picture. When you first connect stdout to a file, connecting `2` to the target is the same file.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, here is how to get the output using command substitution:

OUTP=$(pfctl -tscanners -Ttest 1.1.1.1 2>&1)

Comment: @Laine: When you want to use `$OUTP` (or better `${outp}` lowercase and braces), do not forget quotes: `echo "${OUTP}"` and you get newlines when they were in the original output.